# Linked jQuery document not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to build a image slider for a website. I have written all of the code required for this to work yet I have having trouble making the jQuery respond or work within the HTML document.

The HTML of the page is:

```js
var currentIndex = 0,
  items = $('.container div'),
  itemsAmt = items.length;

function cycleItems() {
  var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
  items.hide();
  item.css('display', 'inline-block');
}

var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemsAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
}, 3000);

$('.next').click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemsAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex -= 1;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = itemsAmt - 1;
  }
  cycleItems();
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
}

.next {
  right: 5px;
}

.prev {
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/sliderstyle.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/sliderjs.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="demo">
    <button class="next">Next</button>
    <button class="prev">Previous</button>
    <div class="container">
      <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <img src="./img/1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./img/2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="./img/3.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fundamentals of HTML/CSS and JavaScript. Might sound like a troll, but I'm serious. If you learn those basics (and how browsers render, what HTTP status codes there are from servers etc) you would be well-equipped to debug this very quickly and would be considered a skill in the professional space, 1-up'ing your competition because you don't have to spend hours on stack overflow looking for tailor-made solutions.  Again, might sound like a troll, it's not, just solid advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you can consider:
Either wait for the ready state of the DOM tree with, which results into that all DOM elements and references are generated correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//your code here
});
```

This would be the much safer way. Another possible solution is to include your JavaScript files at the bottom of your code e.g. before the `</body>` HTML-Tag. Also here it may be important to wait for the DOM ready state to reduce the possibility of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use document ready

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```